# Why does node* root = malloc(sizeof(int)) allocate 16 bytes of memory instead of 4?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm messing around with Linked List type data structures to get better with pointers and structs in C, and I don't understand this.

I thought that `malloc` returned the address of the first block of memory of size `sizeof` to the pointer.

In this case, my `node struct` looks like this and is 16 bytes:

```
typedef struct node{
    int index;  
    struct node* next;  
}node;
```

I would expect that if I try to do this: `node* root = malloc(sizeof(int))`

`malloc` would allocate only a block of 4 bytes and return the address of that block to the pointer `node`.

However, I'm still able to assign a value to index and get root to point to a next node, as such:

```
root->index = 0;
root->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

And the weirdest part is that if I try to run: `printf("size of pointer root: %lu \n", sizeof(*root));`

I get `size of pointer root: 16`, when I clearly expected to see `4`.

What's going on?

**EDIT**: I just tried `malloc(sizeof(char))` and it still tells me that `*root` is 16 bytes.

Comment: What happens to the the `next` bit in the calculation?

Comment: @EdHeal, I'm sorry I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Undefined Behavior means anything can happen, including appearing to work.

Comment: You have two items in the `struct` - one being `next`

Comment: @EdHeal, right, but why am I getting 16 bytes of memory when I ask for 4? Is it that I just happen to get lucky that an extra 12 bytes contiguous to the 4 I asked for are free?

Comment: You are asking for the size of the `index` along with the the size of `next`

Comment: You didn't get 16 bytes. It's like if you buy a property  with no fences. Just because you can walk into your neighbour's property does not mean you got an extra property that you didn't ask for. C allows you to shoot yourself in the foot if you want to. If you code in such a way to stomp over memory you shouldn't then C won't explicitly stop you.

Comment: @kaylum, so is it what I asked Ed? I just happened to get lucky that an extra 12 bytes contiguous to the 4 I asked for were free?

Comment: No you got unlucky. If you were lucky the program would crash and prompt you to fix the error. The worst bugs are the ones that don't trigger bad effects until the most inconvenient times. But yes, you just happened to access memory that did not immediately manifest in a crash (though it doesn't mean that memory is free - someone just hasn't yelled at you yet to get off their property).

Comment: @kaylum, I see your point about lucky vs unlucky, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a few things going on here, plus one more that probably isn't a problem in this example but is a problem in general.

1) `int` isn't guaranteed to be 4 bytes, although in most C compiler implementations they are.  I would double check `sizeof(int)` to see what you get.

2) `node* root = malloc(sizeof(int))` is likely to cause all sorts of problems, because `sizeof(struct node)` is not the same as an `int`.  As soon as you try to access `root->next`, you have undefined behavior.

3) `sizeof(struct node)` is not just an `int`, it is an `int` and a `pointer`.  Pointers are (as far as I know, someone quote the standard if not) the same size throughout a program depending on how it was compiled (32-bit vs 64-bit, for example).  You can easily check this on your compiler with `sizeof(void*)`.  It should be the same as `sizeof(int*)` or `sizeof(double*)` or any other pointer type.

4) Your struct *should* be `sizeof(int) + sizeof(node*)`, but isn't guaranteed to be.  For example, say I have this struct:

```
struct Example
{
  char c;
  int i;
  double d;
};
```

You'd expect its size to be `sizeof(char) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(double)`, which is 1 + 4 + 8 = 13 on my compiler, but in practice it won't be.  Compilers can "align" members internally to match the underlying instruction architecture, which generally will increase the structs size.  The tradeoff is that they can access data more quickly.  This is not standardized and varies from one compiler to another, or even different versions of the same compiler with different settings.  [You can learn more about it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

5) Your line `printf("size of pointer root: %lu \n", sizeof(*root))` is not the size of the pointer to root, it is the size of the struct root.  This leads me to believe that you are compiling this as 64-bit code, so `sizeof(int)` is 4, and `sizeof(void*)` is 8, and they are being aligned to match the system word (8 bytes), although I can't be positive without seeing your compiler, system, and settings.  If you want to know the size of the pointer to root, you need to do `sizeof(node*)` or `sizeof(root)`.  You dereference the pointer in your version, so it is the equivalent of saying `sizeof(node)`

Bottom line, is that the weirdness you are experiencing is *undefined behavior*.  You aren't going to find a concrete answer, and just because you think you find a pattern in the behavior doesn't mean you should use it (unless you want impossible to find bugs later that make you miserable).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. Re: 4) When you talk about underlying architecture, is this about *word* size, where word is what the fastest cache memory can process at once or something like that? And re: 5) I checked and my pointers are size 8 bytes and ints are 4 bytes. The reason I was printing out sizeof(*root) was to get the size of the structure itself. I was expecting 4 bytes but I guess the type setting is really what tells C how to navigate the memory block reserved at that address, right? Kind of like an array of int would navigate 4 bytes by 4 bytes.

Comment: On 4, it is closely related to the word size, but I do not know for certain if it varies across x86 to ARM for example.  As far as I understand it is just not standardized, and each compiler can define it how they want.  It is my understanding that it *should* be the word size, unless the data type overflows the word size (8 byte `double` on a 32-bit x86), in which case I have no idea.

Comment: On 5, I meant to clarify that your text in the `printf` is incorrect, as that is not the pointer, it is the data type (although your comment seems to clarify that was your intent).  The structure would absolutely be larger than 4 bytes since you say your int is 4 bytes, so it needs more room for the pointer.  I think you have the right general idea in understanding what the alignment means, you should ask a separate question or [browse these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+struct+alignment) if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what system (M$ or linux, 32bit or 64bit) but your assumptions about memory allocation are wrong. Memory allocations are aligned to some specified boundary to guarantee all allocations for supported types are properly aligned - typically it is 16 bytes for 64bit mode.

Check this - libc manual:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Aligned-Memory-Blocks.html

> The address of a block returned by malloc or realloc in GNU systems is
>   always a multiple of eight (or sixteen on 64-bit systems). If you need
>   a block whose address is a multiple of a higher power of two than
>   that, use aligned_alloc or posix_memalign. aligned_alloc and
>   posix_memalign are declared in stdlib.h.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things happening here. First, ***C has no bounds checking***. C doesn't track how much memory you allocated to a variable, either. You didn't allocate enough memory for a node, but C doesn't check that. The following "works", but really it doesn't.

```
node* root = malloc(sizeof(int));

root->index = 0;
root->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

Since there wasn't enough memory allocated for the struct, someone else's memory has been overwritten. You can see this by printing out the pointers.

```
printf("sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(int));
printf("root: %p\n", root);
printf("&root->index: %p\n", &root->index);
printf("&root->next: %p\n", &root->next);

sizeof(int): 4
root: 0x7fbde5601560
&root->index: 0x7fbde5601560
&root->next: 0x7fbde5601568
```

I've only allocated 4 bytes, so I'm only good from 0x7fbde5601560 to 0x7fbde5601564. `root->index` is fine, but `root->next` is writing to someone else's memory. It might be unallocated, in which case it might get allocated to some other variable and then you'll see weird things happening. Or it might be memory for some existing variable, in which case it will overwrite that memory and cause very difficult to debug memory problems.

But it didn't go so far out of bounds so as to walk out of the memory allocated to the whole process, so it didn't trigger your operating system's [memory protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection). That's usually a [segfault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

Note `root->next` is 8 bytes after `root->index` because this is a 64 bit machine and so [elements of a struct align on 8 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86). If you were to put another integer into the struct after index, next would still be 8 bytes off.

There's another possibility: even though you only asked for `sizeof(int)` memory, `malloc` probably allocated more. Most memory allocators do their work in chunks. But this is all implementation defined, so your code still has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

> And the weirdest part is that if I try to run: printf("size of pointer root: %lu \n", sizeof(*root)); I get size of pointer root: 16, when I clearly expected to see 4.

`root` is a pointer to a struct, and you'd expect `sizeof(root)` to be pointer sized, 8 bytes on a 64 bit machine to address 64 bits of memory.

`*root` dereferences that pointer, `sizeof(*root)` is the actual size of the struct. That's 16 bytes. (4 for the integer, 4 for padding, 8 for the struct pointer). Again, C doesn't track how much memory you allocated, it only tracks what the size of the variable is supposed to be.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies a lot of things.